# How do I move the Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml file to a different location?

Tags: reinforced-typings

This is supposed to be achievable now per this PR:
https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/pull/210

I've tried adding something like this to my csproj file:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RtSettingsXml Condition="HasTrailingSlash('$(ProjectDir)')">$(ProjectDir)Properties\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml</RtSettingsXml>
        <RtSettingsXml Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(ProjectDir)')">$(ProjectDir)\Properties\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml</RtSettingsXml>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an SDK style csproj, then `$(ProjectDir)` won't be resolved at the time your property group is being read. Use the `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

As per @QuillFancyson's answer, here is what worked for me:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RtSettingsXml Condition="HasTrailingSlash('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)Build\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml</RtSettingsXml>
    <RtSettingsXml Condition="!HasTrailingSlash('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml</RtSettingsXml>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

...just change the `...Build\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml` parts to refer to the directory and file name you are using (in my case I created a `Build` directory in my project's root folder, then kept the `Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml` file name, so the resulting path is `Build\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml` as seen above).

**UPDATE:** this version works too by using [MSBuild property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-property-functions) to take care of the slash:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RtSettingsXml>
      $([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))Build\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml
    </RtSettingsXml>
  </PropertyGroup>
```